# Django bootstrap alerts not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with this.

I'm trying to make my app looks better with bootstrap alert, I have one alert to add an item and other alert to delete an item.

When I add an item my alert looks great and work fine but when I delete the item it's not working properly.. Only shows my message with no bootstrap alert....

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I got:

```
<div class="container">
  {% if messages %}
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <p{% if message.tags == "success" %} class="alert alert-success "{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
      {% if message == 'danger' %}
      <p{% if message.tags == 'danger'  %} class="alert alert-danger"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}


    </div>

  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

**Views for my success msg**
messages.success(request, 'Has been added!.')

**Views for my danger msg**
messages.error(request, 'Has been deleted!.')

**Thanks in advance..!**

**EDIT**

I solved my problem as Silvio answered to my question. worked great with every bootstrap alert but the `alert-danger` to make it work I had to edit my `settings.py` to something like this:

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants
MESSAGE_TAGS = {message_constants.DEBUG: 'debug',
                message_constants.INFO: 'info',
                message_constants.SUCCESS: 'success',
                message_constants.WARNING: 'warning',
                message_constants.ERROR: 'danger',}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are using the wrong HTML markup for Bootstrap:

```
{% if messages %}
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" role="alert">
          <p>{{ message }}</p>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Note that you were using a `<p>` tag instead of a `<div>`. Also maybe you can use the `{{ message.tags }}` directly.

Comment: This answer is mostly true but still a problem for message.tags=error

Answer (score 20):

As an update to the author's question, only the tags that are being overridden need to be listed in settings:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags

In this case (Bootstrap looking for "danger", but Django providing "error"):

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}
```